# Use variables in Azure Functions out binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions

I'm using Azure functions with javascript, and i would like to modify the out binding of `path` in my functions. For example this is my `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "container/{variableCreatedInFunction}-{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "storagename_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
```

I Would like to set `{variableCreatedInFunction}` in `index.js`, for example:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const data = req.body
    const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    const variableCreatedInFunction = `dir/path/${date}`
    if (data) {
        var responseMessage = `Good`
        var statusCode = 200
        context.bindings.outputBlob = data
    } else {
        var responseMessage = `Bad`
        var statusCode = 500
    }
    context.res = {
        status: statusCode,
        body: responseMessage
    };
}
```

Couldn't find any way to this, is it possible?

Comment: javascript don't support imperative binding pattern, so we can not use IBinder. We need to get value from the param of request or from the body of the request. Any other doubts?

Comment: I need to get the out blob name in the function. Or get rand-guid at least in the function.
 Is that possible?  i tried this: `var randGuid = context.bindingData.sys.randGuid` but its not the same guid from the binding

Answer (score 3):

Bindings are resolved before the function executes. You can use `{DateTime}` as a binding expression. It will by default be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ssZ`. You can use `{DateTime:yyyy}` as well (and other formatting patterns, as needed).

Imperative bindings (which is what you want to achieve) is only available in C# and other .NET languages, [the docs says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#binding-at-runtime):

> Binding at runtime In C# and other .NET languages, you can use an
> imperative binding pattern, as opposed to the declarative bindings in
> function.json and attributes. Imperative binding is useful when
> binding parameters need to be computed at runtime rather than design
> time. To learn more, see the [C# developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime) or the [C# script developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#binding-at-runtime).

MS might've added it to JS as well by now, since I'm pretty sure I read that exact section more than a year ago, but I can't find anything related to it. Maybe you can do some digging yourself.

If your request content is JSON, the alternative is to include the path in the request, e.g.:

```json
{
  "mypath":"a-path",
  "data":"yourdata"
}
```

You'd then be able to do declarative binding like this:

```json
{
  "name": "outputBlob",
  "path": "container/{mypath}-{rand-guid}",
  "connection": "storagename_STORAGE",
  "direction": "out",
  "type": "blob"
}
```

In case you need the name/path to your `Blob`, you'd probably have to chain two functions together, where one acts as the entry point and path generator, while the other is handling the `Blob` (and of course the binding).
It would go something like this:

- Declare 1st function with `HttpTrigger` and `Queue` (output).
- Have the 1st function create your "random" path containing `{date}-{guid}`.
- Insert a message into the Queue output with the content `{"mypath":"2020-10-15-3f3ecf20-1177-4da9-8802-c7ad9ada9a33", "data":"some-data"}` (replacing the date and guid with your own generated values, of course...)
- Declare 2nd function with `QueueTrigger` and your `Blob`-needs, still binding the `Blob` path as before, but without `{rand-guid}`, just `{mypath}`.
- The `mypath` is now used both for the blob output (declarative) and you have the information available from the queue message.

Comment: Is there any way that i can get the blob name in my function?

Comment: @yaniv055 Try change the `direction` of `outputBlob` to `inout` instead of `out`, and debug the context to see if the name (with the guid) is available then. I'm not sure if it works with JS, though.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in js:
`ReadWrite access is not supported. Pick either Read or Write.`

Comment: @yaniv055 I see. You could chain 2 functions together, if you really need the name. See updated answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possiable to set dynamic variable in .js and let the binding know.

The value need to be given in advance, but this way may achieve your requirement:

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.bindings.outputBlob = "This is a test.";
    context.done();
    context.res = {
        body: 'Success.'
    };
}
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "test/{test}",
      "connection": "str",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "str":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

Or you can just put the output logic in the body of function. Just use the javascript sdk.